# If $aRb \land bRc$ never occurs, is a relation considered transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Studying relation properties. My definition of a transitive relation is as follows:

> A relation is transitive if and only if $\forall a,b,c \in A [aRb \land bRc \implies aRc]$

My question is: if $aRb \land bRc$ never occurs in the first place, is the relation considered transitive?

I ask this because when I read $\forall a,b,c \in A [aRb \land bRc \implies aRc]$ I read it as follows: "**when** $a$ relates with $b$ and $b$ relates with $c$, $a$ relates to $c$". But since this **"when"** never happens, there is no condition to evaluate to decide if it is transitive or not.

The same issue occurs with **antisymmetry**, where $\forall a,b \in A[aRb \land bRa \implies a = b]$ - what if $aRb \land bRa$ never occurs in the first place?

**EDIT**

I just remembered that $F_0\implies whatever$ is always $V_0$.... I guess this answers my question... kinda.

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: You may want to look at [Vacous truth.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is *yes* in both cases; these are examples of statements that are *vacuously true*, to use the usual expression. To see why we would want to use this interpretation, ask yourself what it would take in order to show that $R$ is **not** transitive: you’d need to find elements $a,b,c\in A$ such that $a~R~b$, $b~R~c$, and yet $a~\not R~c$. But if there are no elements $a,b,c\in A$ such that $a~R~b$ and $b~R~c$, you can’t possibly find such a counterexample. In short, there is no counterexample to transitivity of $R$, so by default $R$ must be transitive.

Another way to put it: transitivity says that when certain conditions are met, a certain thing has to happen. It says nothing about cases in which those conditions are never met: it requires nothing in those cases, so it cannot possibly fail.

Comment: If they ask me to verify if a relation is transitive or not and this scenario occurs, how should I word it out? Should I say *"it is vacuously true"*?

Comment: @Omega I would say it is. Or I would simply cite it as 'vacuous truth'.

Comment: @Omega: That works. ‘Is this relation transitive?’ ‘Yes, vacuously so.’ ‘Is it true that this relation is transitive?’ ‘Yes, it’s vacuously true’.

Answer (score 5):

Yes...it is...You can consider both properties to hold, *unless there exists a counterexample*:

Transitivity ***fails*** IF AND ONLY IF: $\quad \exists a, b, c \in A[a R b \land bRc \land \lnot (a R c)]$

Likewise for antisymmetry:

Antisymmetry ***fails*** IF AND ONLY IF: $\quad \exists a,b \in A[aRb \land bRa \land  a \neq  b]$

Answer (score 1):

You have an if-then statement, $P\Rightarrow Q$.  If $P$ is false, then the if-then statement is true.  So, if you have a relation where $aRb\wedge bRc$ never occurs, it would be false to state $aRb\wedge bRc$.

Answer (score -1):

On the set $\{-1,1\}$ with $R$ defined $xRy$ if $y=-x$, we see that $R$ is transitive by vacuity.

Comment: @downvoter I made an error in my original calculations. I've corrected this.